# Has the majority of Northern Ireland's business organisations rejected Boris Johnson's latest Brexit plan?

Tags: brexit

The Belfast Telegraph reporting on Boris Johnson's "final offer" to the EU, [states that](https://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/northern-ireland/boris-johnsons-brexit-deal-is-threat-to-peace-in-northern-ireland-says-former-pm-tony-blair-38567226.html):

> Mr Johnson's current plans would see Northern Ireland apply EU rules on goods, but stay in a customs territory with the UK. [...]
>
> The DUP are the only major party in Northern Ireland supporting the proposals, with it being rejected by Sinn Fein, SDLP, Alliance, the Green Party, UUP and the TUV.
>
> It has also been **rejected by the majority of Northern Ireland's business organisations**.

It does not get into any details on the latter statement. Is it correct by some quantifiable measure?

Comment: What's a business *organization*, compared to just *a business*? In other words, is that just "appeal to authority"? Good question.

Comment: @fredsbend I'm guessing things like [CBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederation_of_British_Industry)